# How to allow user to set web part size and height dynamically

Tags: sharepoint

How to allow user to set web part size and height dynamically?
My requirement is user can dynamically set the height and weight of the webpart.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create two new properties that can store values per user. Here is the discussion link from sharepoint forums that can be helpful:http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/313aa8be-8795-4c3d-99b3-25dfc22aca27/

Here is the same one with screen: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34232/custom-webpart-to-set-and-get-property-per-user-personalizationscope-user